# DisplayMetrics returning all zero

Tags: android

I am trying to access some DisplayMetrics data and everything is returning zero. This is how I am initializing display metrics object:

```
DisplayMetrics display = new DisplayMetrics();
```

and when I call `display.heightPixels` it's just zero. Do I need a permission or something to access `DisplayMetrics`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not how to use `DisplayMetrics`.

This is how:

```
final WindowManager w = (WindowManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
final Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
final DisplayMetrics m = new DisplayMetrics();
d.getMetrics(m);

// m now contains reliable data
```

Comment: And, oh, by the way : this question could have been avoided if you had really read the documentation... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

Comment: Your methods are deprecated can you suggest latest one

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);`, before call the method `display.heightPixels`

Answer (score 0):

You should call:
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(display);

before calling
display.heightPixels