# How to detect screen resolution in Android at python/kivy/pyjnius?

Tags: python, android, kivy, pyjnius

I need to know screen resolution in pixels in application that is created in Python with Kivy. The specific question concerns Android. Kivy itself unfortunately doesn't want to transfer information obtained from GL to user, so I have to use workarounds. Under Android it's pyjnius, according to [pyjnius manual](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/stable/android.html#get-the-dpi) and [DisplayMetrics manual](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics) I've tried this code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Canvas, Rectangle, Color

myheight=-100
mywidth=-100
myDPI=-100
gDPI=-100
Window.fullsceen = True

if platform == 'android':
    from jnius import autoclass
    DisplayMetrics = autoclass('android.util.DisplayMetrics')
    metrics = DisplayMetrics()
    gDPI=metrics.getDeviceDensity()
    myheight = metrics.heightPixels
    mywidth = metrics.widthPixels
    myDPI = metrics.densityDpi

class MainApp(App):
  def build(self):
    b = Button(text="Height: "+ str(myheight) + "\nWidth: " + str(mywidth) + "\nDPI: " + str(myDPI) + "\ngetDPI: " + str(gDPI)
+ '\nWindow.size:' + str(Window.size), color = [0,0,0,1])
    with b.canvas:
       Color(0,1,1, .2)
       Rectangle(size = Window.size, pos = (0,0))
    return b

MainApp().run()
```

But in the result I have all three values = 0, and window size = 800px independently from platfrom. Pyjnius manual use method getDeviceDensity() that is not documented in DisplayMetrics methods. Are there any alternative methods how can I detect screen resolution in kivy under android? Can I call directly SDL2 to detect screen resolution and where it has to be done properly?
The screenshot (as requested) is attached.[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Kivy itself unfortunately doesn't want to transfer information obtained from GL to user

I'm not sure what you mean by this, `kivy.core.window.Window.size` should give the gl display size. This is not, of course, the same thing as the screen resolution that you asked for - I'm not sure if that matters to you.

> But in the result I have all three values = 0

This appears to be for the reason described e.g. in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123923/displaymetrics-returning-all-zero).

Comment: Surely I've tried it but Kivy window size has 800 px size. I need to know native resolution. As for the second variant - how should I use getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics) in pyjnius?

Comment: The Kivy window size should represent the drawable window size in pixels. If it doesn't, that's a bug. Could you draw a Rectangle with pos (0, 0) and size Window.size, and post a screenshot showing that it doesn't fill the screen?

Comment: And for the pyjnius part, the method I linked should probably work in pyjnius.

Comment: The sceenshot is on linux, but the question is about Android?

Comment: As for pyjnius: logcat:
python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
python  :    File "/home/osboxes/KivyHelloWorld/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 17, in <module>
python  :  NameError: name 'getWindowManager' is not defined
python  : Python for android ended.

Comment: That error is because you wrote some bad code as it says, it isn't related to your original question. If you're blindly copying and pasting from the linked SO question, your problem is that the answers referring to getWindowManager aren't including the class instance of which this is a method. I'm still not clear, why doesn't Window.size do what you want on Android?

Comment: The main problem is the lack of documentation, at least for pyjnius. How could I use that is not documented for python at all rather than blindly? Window.size has the correct values at Android (Android 7 at least). At Windows and at Linux it is always 800x600. I'd prefer to have platform-independent solution (e.g. to ask SDL2). It's a pity that kivy refuses to transfer basic GL parameters to the user...
I guess window.size is not size of the screen, it seems to the default window size created by OS. Moreover, even under Android I get not the screen size, but the window size - statusbar.

Comment: Your issue here isn't related to pyjnius' documentation, it's because you don't know anything about the java apis you're trying to call. Ultimately you have to look some of this up and understand a little java in order to call them from Python.

Comment: About the "always 800x600", do you mean the Window.size doesn't update even if you resize the window? That would be a bug if so.

Comment: Also, you keep talking about "basic GL parameters" but simultaneously complaining about getting the window size rather than the screen size...but the window size in pixels _is_ the GL region size you're asking for. If you want the size of the physical screen in pixels, that's something else.

Comment: You also keep suggesting Kivy "refuses" to give you the information you want, but that's a strange phrasing. It would be more normal to say that Kivy doesn't have an API to expose this information. The reason it doesn't have an API to access the screen size is that nobody has implemented it (probably because people usually don't care about it), not because it wouldn't be a welcome addition.

Comment: I'm not sure if possibly `PythonActivity = autoclass("org.kivy.android.PythonActivity"); context = cast("android.content.Context", PythonActivity.mActivity); metrics = context.GetResources().getDisplayMetrics()` might do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
DisplayMetrics = autoclass('android.util.DisplayMetrics')
Context = autoclass('android.content.Context')
PythonActivity = autoclass("org.kivy.android.PythonActivity")

metrics = DisplayMetrics()
a = PythonActivity.mActivity
wm = a.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)
d = wm.getDefaultDisplay()
d.getMetrics(metrics)
```

Answer (score 0):

This example will work

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.app import App

from jnius import autoclass

PythonActivity = autoclass("org.kivy.android.PythonActivity")
activity = PythonActivity.mActivity
displayMetrics = activity.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()

KV = '''
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        id: container
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: dp(10)
        spacing: dp(10)
        
        Label:
            id: lbl
            halign: 'center'

        Widget:
'''


class Test(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)

        self.screen.ids.lbl.text += f'Width: {self.get_screen_width_dpi()}\n'
        self.screen.ids.lbl.text += f'Height: {self.get_screen_height_dpi()}\n'
        self.screen.ids.lbl.text += f'DPI: {displayMetrics.densityDpi}\n'

    @staticmethod
    def get_screen_width_dpi():
        return displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density

    @staticmethod
    def get_screen_height_dpi():
        return displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density

    def build(self):
        return self.screen


Test().run()
```